# Why do requests return "None"?

Tags: python, return, python-requests

```
import requests

def get(url):
    if url[:7] == 'http://':
        if url[7:11] == 'www.':
            print url
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return 'ok'

            else:
                return 'error'
        else:
            print(url)
            url = 'http://www.' + url[7:]
            get(url)
    else:
        print(url)
        url = 'http://' + url
        get(url)

print get('example.com')
```

Can anyone tell me why this code is returning "None"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question will get better responses if you use a more descriptive title and include your question in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the result from the recursive calls to `get()` function.

You need to return the result from the recursive calls to `get()` function , Example -

```
import requests

def get(url):
    if url[:7] == 'http://':
        if url[7:11] == 'www.':
            print url
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return 'ok'

            else:
                return 'error'
        else:
            print(url)
            url = 'http://www.' + url[7:]
            return get(url)
    else:
        print(url)
        url = 'http://' + url
        return get(url)

print get('example.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the return value of your recursive calls. You need to explicitly return those:

```
return get(url)
```

just like you'd have to handle the return value of any other kind of function call.

Recursion isn't really the best solution here; just adjust the URL before trying to retrieve it:

```
def get(url):
    if not url.startswith('http://'):
        url = 'http://' + url
    if not url.startswith('http://www.'):
        url = 'http://www.' + url[7:]

    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return 'ok'
    else:
        return 'error'
```

or better still, use the [`urlparse` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to update url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is a recursive call you have to return each method call

```
return get(url)
```

That is when you call initially `get(url)` that method again calls `get(url)` due to recursive calling SInce the first call did not return any argument and preceded to the second call it will return None the default return argument of a function